# Django 2.0 - Using LoginRequiredMixin and ListView error

Tags: django, django-views, django-class-based-views

I'm trying to make a `ListView` with a form which when I submit returns me the object list. Below is the code for my `views.py`.

```
class ChatListView(ListView):
    model = Chat
    form_class = NewMessageForm
    queryset = model.objects.all().order_by('-created_at')[:20][::-1] #returns 20 latest objects
    template_name = 'chat.html'  

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)        
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('chat')
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

    #code for form in the same view
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)  
        context['form'] = self.form_class
        return context
```

This works for me. But I want this view to only available to log in users. So I added a `LoginRequiredMixin`.

```
class ChatListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Chat
    form_class = NewMessageForm
    queryset = model.objects.all().order_by('-created_at')[:20][::-1]
    template_name = 'chat.html'
    login_url = 'login'
```

(Form got saved in the database but the data doesn't show up in the list view.) When I look at the bash the error is `"POST /chat/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0`. How can I implement the login required thing without this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the `LoginRequiredMixin` is your problem. `POST /chat/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0` is not an error message. It just means that your view returned a 302 redirect response, which is expected since it does `return redirect('chat')`.

I think the problem is that using `[::-1]` to reverse the queryset will cause it to be evaluated and converted to a list immediately. Once you add new items, they will not appear in the queryset until the server has been restarted.

You can fix this by moving the code to the `get_queryset`, so that the queryset is fetched for each request.

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return self.model.objects.all().order_by('-created_at')[:20][::-1]
```

Comment: By the way is the `302` post method a good idea? I've read 
returning `302` is not a good thing. If so how can I change the post method?

Comment: Returning a 302 temporary redirect after a successful post is recommended. It helps prevent duplicate post requests.